# Regex for string comparison by ignoring whitespaces

Tags: regex

Can you pls. help me in obtaining regex for the below statement:

```
UINT32 Address;
```

Here Address is a variable of type `UINT32`, I need to perform string check of `'UINT32 [A-Z_0-9]'`

Here I need to ignore space after `UINT32.` So i need to check

```
UINT32+ignore space+Address.
```

Regards,

Comment: Why not just do string replacement before matching?  Something like `str = str.replace(/UINT32 /g, 'UINT32');`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve and what do you mean by ignore space, but may be `UINT\s+[A-Z_0-9]+` will do. `\s` matches any whitespace character (space, tab, newline) and `\s+` matches any whitespace sequence.